# Suppress error from Unit of Work transaction

Tags: c#, error-handling, transactions, unit-of-work, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to suppress error in code, but MVC action still returns "500 internal server error".

What events are fired in ASP.NET Boilerplate framework after action returns?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]PaymentViewModel model)
{
    var result = false;

    // Storing of card must pass
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Catch business exception, but storing
    }

    return Json(new { result });
}
```

Comment: the 500 is only what the client browser will see. there should be sufficient detail information available from within the debugger, or if this is not a development instance, from the windows application event log of the web server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recover in a `catch` block, begin a `UnitOfWork` with `RequiresNew`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]PaymentViewModel model)
{
    var result = false;

    // Storing of card must pass
    try
    {
        using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            // ...

            await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            await uow.CompleteAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Catch business exception, but storing
    }

    return Json(new { result });
}
```

Further explanation: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#2732 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2732#issuecomment-351926713)